# How to convert data from AWS lambda node.js to JSONObject in Java

Tags: json, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

My code snippet of lambda is

```
dynamodb.query( params
, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        context.done(err);
    }
    else {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); // successful response
        var size = data.Items.length;
        console.log("size:"+ size);
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (size));
        console.log("rand" + rand);
        var ret = data.Items[rand].content;
        console.log(ret);
        context.succeed(JSON.stringify(ret));
    }
```

My AWS Lambda log of ("console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); // successful response") is

```
{"Items":[{"content":{"S":"content1"}},{"content":{"S":"content2"}}],"Count":2,"ScannedCount":2}
```

And result of "JSON.stringify(ret)" is

```
{"S":"content1"}
```

In my Android code, call this API and just show the result.
But it only showed "java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"

I wonder how to convert to JSONObject in Android.

I used this code in Android

```
new JSONObject(notice).getJSONObject("S");
```

Comment: double check your `notice` variable with debugging. The "cannot convert" error is usually thrown when there is a syntax issue.

Comment: Hi @donkon 
notice variable is actuallry "{"S":"content1"}" . It doesn't wrong. so it makes me crazy. What shoud i do checking more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are calling `getJSONObject`. The object you are getting is a `String`.

```
{"S":"content1"}
^JSON    ^String
```

You should be calling `get`

```
JSONObject jsonNotice = new JSONObject("{\"S\":\"hello, world\"}");
String contentsOfS = jsonNotice.get("S");
```

The method `getJSONObject` is for nested JSON objects:

```
{"S": {"foo": "bar"}}
^JSON ^JSON
```

Comment: String contentsOfS = jsonNotice.getString("S");
this is what i resolved thing! 
Thanks very much!